\mathbb{f} produces a strange character
I am trying to have a blackboard symbol of the character 'f'. Here is a minimal example which I have tried.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}    % Typical maths 


\begin{document}

$\mathbb{f}$
$\mathbb{R}$

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE! And what is your result? Can you show a screenshot please? Please add how you do compile ...

Normally, the bb fonts only covers upper case letter.

Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/311452/82917 https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281165/82917

Several Unicode-math fonts provide not only blackboard uppercase letters but also blackboard lowercase letters and digits. For example LatinModern, Termes, Pagella, Bonum, Stix, ...
Following example uses Pagella Math Unicode font with OpTeX:
\fontfam[pagella]

Test: $\bbchar f, 0$.

\bye

I did test of many Unicode math fonts using OpTeX:
\def\test[#1]{\doloadmath\fontfam[#1] #1: $\bbchar R, C, f, g, 1024$. \par}

\test[LMfonts]
\test[Termes]
\test[Bonum]
\test[Pagella]
\test[Schola]
\test[NewCM]
\test[STIX]
\test[XITS]
\test[STIXtwo]
\test[Libertinus]
\test[KPfonts]
\test[Dejavu]
\test[Erewhon]
\test[EBGaramond]
\test[Xcharter]
\test[Fira]
\test[Neohellenic]
\test[OldStandard]

\bye

and the result is:

We can see that only KPfonts, Fira and Neohellenic don't support desired characters.

For use with pdfLaTeX, most blackboard (aka double-struck) math font packages -- including the defaults used by LaTeX/AMS -- provide glyphs only for uppercase Latin letters (A thru Z).
If you're interested in characters with serifs, an interesting math font is Libertinus, as it provides glyphs for lowercase Latin letters (a thru z) as well. To access this package's blackboard-bold glyphs, I suggest you run
\usepackage[bb=libus]{mathalfa}

in the preamble.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bb=libus]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}
$\mathbb{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$ 

$\mathbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
\end{document}


According to the documentation of amssymb:

We call the amsfonts package to do the font setup that we need.

and if we review the users' guide of amsfont, it is clearly stated in Section 3.3:

The amsfonts package defines a “math alphabet” command \mathbb for printing letters of the blackboard bold alphabet [...]. This alphabet is restricted to uppercase only (no lowercase, no numerals).

Lowercase blackboard symbols can be added to the \mathbbcommand by other packages, as suggested e.g. here.

Welcome to TeX.SE.
